# hotkey for pdflatex in lyx

Tags: lyx

I would like to define a hot-key in LyX to compile my document to `pdflatex`. How can I do this? I looked at the currently available hotkeys in there but couldn't not find one associated with this function.

Comment: Does ctrl + R do what you want (the shortcut works on Linux, not sure about other OS)? Or you have the default output format set to something other than `pdflatex`?

Comment: i'm on windows: unfortunately the ctrl + r doesn't work for me at all (same with clicking on the eye icon on the toolbar). i'm on lyx 2.1.0 and windows 7

Comment: is this true for all document? It is strange that the eyes icon is not enabled. If it is only true for some documents, can you post an example .lyx file (it is just a text file)?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? What happens when you try? Under the Document-menu you should see what Ctrl + R does I think, for example here the fourth entry is *View [PDF (pdflatex)]  Ctrl + R*.

Comment: true for all docs. when i press it i could tell that lyx does something and adobe viewer twitches, but nothing is displayed (ie there is no document that appears)